# no classes in JSX via reactify

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to render the following component:

```
function deviceready() {
  ReactDOM.render(
    <div class="container">
      <h1>Hello <small>World</small></h1>
      <button class="button-primary" onclick="initFacebook()">Login with Facebook</button>
    </div>,
    document.getElementById('frame')
  );
}
```

...With the `reactify` `gulp` plugin. However the attributes don't get compiled. `class="container"` and `class="button-primary`" and `onclick="initFacebook()"` do not appear in my generated HTML.

I'm aware that [custom attributes are not supported](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/jsx-gotchas.html) but these are attributes defined by HTML spec. Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice the differences pointed out in Facebook's [JSX in-depth](http://facebook.github.io/react/docs/jsx-in-depth.html#html-tags-vs.-react-components) article.

`class` should be `className`

Also notice the [Event System](http://facebook.github.io/react/docs/events.html); the prop names don't match up exactly with the HTML attribute names

`onclick` should be `onClick`

Comment: Ahh; there's a lot of FM to RT of.

Comment: I wasn't allowed to for the first 8 minutes!